# How to compare items in an object nested in an array with an object which has an array of items in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, compare

I'm trying to find recipes which match Authors of my searchArray. The searchArray is an array of authors in an object. The recipes I'm matching this searchArray with, are objects in an array.

I've changed the array to a string, thinking that this would make matching more easy. I also changed the searchArray and the Authors in the recipes toLowerCase() and then tried to find recipes matching at least 1 of the authors in the searchArray.

If someone searches with only the first name, then any recipe with an author with that first name is fine. However, if someone searches with first and last name, then the author in the recipe should be an exact match, that's why the first if statement has (" "), indicating a space between first and last name.

Is my way of thinking wrong or am I writing very bad functions (or all of these errors in my brain):

```
const searchRecipeWithAuthor = (searchArray) => {
  const { authors } = searchArray;
  const searchAuthor = authors.toString().toLowerCase();
    // console.log(searchAuthor); // tested and works 

  const matchingRecipes = cakeRecipes.filter(({ Author}) => {
    // console.log(Author)); // gives all Authors as string
    const recipeAuthor = Author.toLowerCase();
    // console.log(recipeAuthor); // tested and works
    
    if (searchAuthor.includes(" ")) {
       // console.log(searchAuthor); // tested and works
      if (searchAuthor === recipeAuthor) {
        // can't test from this part, dus to TypeError referencing const recipeAuthor = //Author.toLowerCase();  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')
        return true;
      } else {
        if (recipeAuthor.includes(searchAuthor)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return matchingRecipes.map((recipe) => recipe[0]); 
};  

console.log(searchRecipeWithAuthor(searchParams));
```

I've shared the code with still some console.log statements in it, to check which parts weren't working. Halfway I couldn't check anymore. I get the following Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at /home/runner/JS-module-7-assignment-cake-search/index.js:59:33
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at searchRecipeWithAuthor (/home/runner/JS-module-7-assignment-cake-search/index.js:57:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/JS-module-7-assignment-cake-search/index.js:77:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

The line this Error message is referring to, is

```
const recipeAuthor = Author.toLowerCase();
    // console.log(recipeAuthor); // works
```

When I tried console.log, it did give me all the authors of all the recipes in lowercase.

Comment: I don't see any way this can happen if `console.log(Authors)` shows a string.

Comment: Do you mean the error message shouldn't refer to recipeAuthor? Error messages don't always point to the exact mistake. Or do you mean Author destructuring itself is wrong the way I did it?

Comment: I mean if `console.log(Author)` shows a string, the destructuring worked and, you shouldn't get this error from `Author.toLowerCase()`. It can only happen if the log shows `undefined`.

Comment: I am so confused by what is supposed to be an array and what an object. Your parameter is called `searchArray` but then you extract a property called `authors` from it. You also extract the property `Authors` from your recipies (the line with filter) - but then at the end you do `recipe[0]` which makes me think recipies are also arrays - but earlier they were objects. Maybe give us some example of the data structures you are using, because from your code alone it's rather unclear if/where you are working with arrays and where with objects.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, both of you. The problem has been found: type error kept happening because one of the recipeAuthors had a null value. I kept looking for a reason of type error in my own code, but it was in the data I was matching with!

Objects with recipes are all stored in an array.  And my assignment is to look for recipes which match some authors in an array (searchArray) which is stored in an object.

Should I delete this question, as this particular error was caused by the data I was matching with and not by my code?